# Extra bracket in the equation in one editor but not in another one. Why?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I have tried to compile the next equation on the overleaf.com :

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq20d}
\delta(x)=\begin{cases}
           \frac{1}{h} \left(\frac{3}{2} y_{n}-4y_{n+1} +\frac{5}{2} y_{n+2} \right.    \nonumber \\
           + \left. h^{3} \left(\frac{61}{6720}f_{n} +\frac{599}{840}f_{n+1} +\frac{353}{336}f_{n+2} \right.\right. \nonumber \\
           - \left.\left. \frac{27}{2240}f_{n+\frac{8}{3}} +\frac{61}{840}f_{n+3}\right)\right),
           & x_{n} \le x\le x_{n+3}, \\
           %
           \frac{1}{h} \left(-\frac{3}{2} y_{n+3} +2y_{n+4} -\frac{1}{2} y_{n+5} \right. \nonumber \\
           +\left. h^3 \left(\frac{13}{224}f_{n+3} +\frac{1399}{4200}35f_{n+4}\right.\right.\nonumber \\
           -\left.\left.\frac{23}{168}f_{n+5} +\frac{783}{5600}f_{n+\frac{17}{3}}
           -\frac{17}{280}f_{n+6} \right)\right),
           & x_{n+3} < x\le x_{n+6}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

but I have the compile error:

> Argument of \frac has an extra }.  \par l.314 \frac
>   {1}{h} \left(\frac{3}{2} y_{n}-4y_{n+1} +\frac{5}{2} y...

Unfortunatly, I can't see this equation here but I have tried to type it on stats.stackexchange.com and result is below:

[image]

**Question:**
How to fix the error on the overleaf's editor?

Comment: I can't replicate your error. Are you loading [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)?

Comment: For MathJax preview I recommend [mathb.in](http://mathb.in/149770).

Comment: @Werner, thank for comment, I don't load this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the need for `amsmath`, I fixed the order of brackets `[]`, and parentheses`()` and used `\biggl`/`\biggr` instead of `\left`/`\right`.

From the point of view of styles, it is recommended to use two equations instead of `cases` environment when the cases span multiple lines (see section 12.35 of [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html) which discusses `cases`). You are free to follow that advice or just stick to your original representation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}\label{eq20d}
\delta(x)&=\frac{1}{h}\biggl[\frac{3}{2} y_{n}-4y_{n+1} +\frac{5}{2} y_{n+2} \nonumber \\
         &\phantom{={}}+ h^{3}\biggl(\frac{61}{6720}f_{n} +\frac{599}{840}f_{n+1} +\frac{353}{336}f_{n+2}\nonumber \\
         &\phantom{={}}-\frac{27}{2240}f_{n+\frac{8}{3}} +\frac{61}{840}f_{n+3}\biggr)\biggr],\quad x_{n}\le x\le x_{n+3},\\
\delta(x)&=\frac{1}{h}\biggl[-\frac{3}{2} y_{n+3} +2y_{n+4} -\frac{1}{2} y_{n+5} \nonumber \\
         &\phantom{={}}+h^3\biggl(\frac{13}{224}f_{n+3} +\frac{1399}{4200}35f_{n+4}-\frac{23}{168}f_{n+5}\nonumber \\
         &\phantom{={}}+\frac{783}{5600}f_{n+\frac{17}{3}}-\frac{17}{280}f_{n+6}\biggr)\biggr],\quad x_{n+3} < x\le x_{n+6}.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)'s use of MathJax comes pre-loaded with the necessary components to allow for using `equation`, `cases`, and other environments. That's why it shows as expected when typing math on that site. Without it - on Overleaf - you need to explicitly load [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to achieve the desired output.

So, add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

[image]

Here would be a minimal example that obtained the above output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \delta(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{h} \bigl[\frac{3}{2} y_n-4y_{n+1} +\frac{5}{2} y_{n+2} \\
    \quad {}+ h^3 \bigl(\frac{61}{6720}f_n +\frac{599}{840}f_{n+1} +\frac{353}{336}f_{n+2} \\
    \quad {}- \frac{27}{2240}f_{n+\frac{8}{3}} +\frac{61}{840}f_{n+3}\bigr)\bigr],
    & x_n \leq x \leq x_{n+3}, \\
    %
    \frac{1}{h} \bigr[-\frac{3}{2} y_{n+3} +2y_{n+4} -\frac{1}{2} y_{n+5} \\
    \quad {}+h^3 \bigl(\frac{13}{224}f_{n+3} +\frac{1399}{4200}35f_{n+4} \\
    \quad {}-\frac{23}{168}f_{n+5} +\frac{783}{5600}f_{n+\frac{17}{3}}
     -\frac{17}{280}f_{n+6} \bigr)\bigr],
    & x_{n+3} < x \leq x_{n+6}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note sure what the factor `35` is doing in the expression...

Comment: open and close parenthesis sizes don't match.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Indeed. Eeeck! I made some more changes.